# Laravel Authentication system This page is unable to handle the request

Tags: laravel-7

When I want to open the admin Authentication system page so it will receive the following errors. also, I'm using localhost XAMPP server.
first Error received:
The allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted.
now I have found the solution so I have increased the memory size limit from php.ini file.

then second Error received:
The maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded.
now I have found the solution so I have increased the maximum execution time from php.ini file.

then the page doesn't open because this page is unable to handle the request.
Is there anyone have a solution?

**Routes:**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard',function (){
        return view('dashboard');
    });
    Route::get('/faculty', function (){
        $title='Faculty Console';
        return view('faculty-dashboard',compact('title'));
    });
    Route::get('/student', function (){
        $title='Student Console';
        return view('user-dashboard',compact('title'));
    });
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function (){
            $student=User::all()->where('user_role','student')->count();
            $employee=User::all()->where('user_role','employee')->count();
            $title='Admin Console';
            return view('admin.admin-dashboard',compact('title','student','employee'));
        });
        Route::resource('selection','SelectionController');
        Route::get('selection/{id}/pivot-create/','SelectionController@pivotCreate')->name('pivotCreate');
        Route::get('selection/{id}/pivot-destroy/','SelectionController@pivotDestroy')->name('pivotDestroy');
    });
});
```

**Auth.php**

```
    'defaults' => [
        //'guard' => 'web',
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

**App/User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table='users';
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

**LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    public function username()
    {
        return 'user_name';
    }
    protected function redirectTo(){
        if (Auth::user()->user_role == 'admin' && Auth::user()->status == '1'){
            //alert()->message('Welcome','Admin')->closeOnClickOutside();
            return '/admin';
        }
        elseif (Auth::user()->user_role == 'faculty' && Auth::user()->status == '1'){
            //alert()->message('Welcome','Faculty')->closeOnClickOutside();
        return '/faculty';
        }
        elseif (Auth::user()->user_role == 'student' && Auth::user()->status == '1'){
            //alert()->message('Welcome','Student')->closeOnClickOutside();
            return '/student';
        }
        else
            return redirect('/login');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        //session()->flash('msg_logout', 'Panel System Successfully Logout');
        alert()->success('You have been logout successfully','GoodBye');
        //session()->flush();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    public function showLoginForm(){
        $title='TheMSC-Sign-In Panel-System';
        return view('log-in',compact('title'));
    }
}
```

**RegisterController**

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers ;
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'cnic' => ['required','string'],
            'user_name'=>[ 'required','string','unique:users','regex:[a-z\d-]'],
            'user_role'=>[ 'required','string'],
            'email' => [ 'required', 'string', 'email:filter,dns'],
            'password' => [ 'required', 'string', 'confirmed','regex:[a-zA-Z\d $&+,:;=?@#|\'<>.^*()%!-]'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'cnic' => $data['cnic'],
            'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
            'user_role' => $data['user_role'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

    }


}
```

Comment: without the code we can't tell

Comment: what type of code do you need?

Comment: the code that is handling that request

Comment: I'm using localhost xampp server.
when I run this command given below:
php artisan db:seed
Error received.
 Allowed memory size of ________  bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ______ bytes).

old memory size limit is 512M

now if we need to increase or decrease the size of memory limit.
I have tried the following size from php.ini
2G
128M
etc...
then it will same Error received.
what we need to do?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file there's something you could change.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $student = User::all()->where('user_role', 'student')->count();
    $employee = User::all()->where('user_role','employee')->count();
    $title = 'Admin Console';
    
    return view('admin.admin-dashboard', compact('title','student','employee'));
});
```

Change

```php
$student = User::all()->where('user_role', 'student')->count();
$employee = User::all()->where('user_role', 'employee')->count();
```

to

```php
$student = User::where('user_role', 'student')->count();
$employee = User::where('user_role', 'employee')->count();
```

Why?
`User::all`:

- Makes the `select * from users`
- Creates an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object with all the rows the database just returned.

This can be memory intensive when you're working with a lot of users. You make this query twice. And then, use `->where(...)` to filter the `Collection`, which again, may be memory intensive when working with a lot of users. Then, you use `->count()` to reduce it to a single value, meaning all the data you queried and made into a `Collection` was for nothing.

If you just want a count, let the database do it. `User::where('user_role', 'student')->count();` translates to a simple `select count(*) from users where user_role = student`.

Comment: I'm using localhost xampp server.
when I run this command given below:
php artisan db:seed
Error received.
 Allowed memory size of ________  bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ______ bytes).

old memory size limit is 512M

now if we need to increase or decrease the size of memory limit.
I have tried the following size from php.ini
2G
128M
etc...
then it will same Error received.
what we need to do?

Comment: Somewhere in your seeds there's something that takes an excessive amount of memory. Try running each seeder class separately with `php artisan db:seed --class=MySeederClass`

Comment: **DatabaseSeeder** `public function run()
    {  factory(User::class,15)->create()->each(function ($user){
            $profile = factory(Profile::class)->make();
            $user->profile()->save($profile);
            $profile->each(function ($profiles){
                $qualification =factory(Qualification::class,3)->make();
                $experience =factory(Experience::class,3)->make();
                $profiles->qualification()->saveMany($qualification);
                $profiles->experience()->saveMany($experience);          });  });  factory(Carousel::class,5)->create(); }`